# How to use the return values of function with apscheduler

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python apscheduler.  I have return values (using variables Out1 & Out2) coming from two functions 'tick & 'tock'.  Out1 & Out2 are each incremented inside the two functions.  I would like to use values of Out1 & Out2 in a third function "Clock".  See my code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

Out1 = 0
Out2 = 1
print('Out1 = {}; Out2 = {}'.format(Out1, Out2))

def tick(Msg):
    print('Tick:  {} {}'.format(datetime.now(), Msg))
    global Out1
    Out1 += 1
    return Out1

def tock(Msg):
    print(' Tock: {} {}'.format(datetime.now(), Msg))
    global Out2
    Out2 += 2
    return Out2

def Clock(Out1, Out2):
    print('\tClock: {} {} {}'.format(datetime.now(), Out1, Out2))
    return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=1,args=["Hello"])
    scheduler.add_job(tock, 'interval', seconds=5,args=["Bye.."])
    scheduler.add_job(Clock, 'interval', seconds=2,args=[tick, tock])
#   scheduler.add_job(Clock, 'interval', seconds=2,args=[tick("HELLO"), tock("BYE")])
    print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')

    try:
        scheduler.start()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
print('\t You made me quit !')
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Out1 = 0; Out2 = 1
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:21.262307 Hello
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:22.263210 Hello
    Clock: 2019-08-18 17:38:22.263978 <function tick at 0x7f299de9dea0> <function tock at 0x7f299c0d66a8>
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:23.263754 Hello
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:24.263164 Hello
    Clock: 2019-08-18 17:38:24.263934 <function tick at 0x7f299de9dea0> <function tock at 0x7f299c0d66a8>
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:25.263955 Hello
 Tock: 2019-08-18 17:38:25.264638 Bye..
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:26.263757 Hello
    Clock: 2019-08-18 17:38:26.264502 <function tick at 0x7f299de9dea0> <function tock at 0x7f299c0d66a8>
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:27.263805 Hello
```

How do I get output such as:

```
Out1 = 0; Out2 = 1
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:21.262307 Hello
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:22.263210 Hello
    Clock: 2019-08-18 17:38:22.263978 2 1
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:23.263754 Hello
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:24.263164 Hello
    Clock: 2019-08-18 17:38:24.263934 4 1
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:25.263955 Hello
 Tock: 2019-08-18 17:38:25.264638 Bye..
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:26.263757 Hello
    Clock: 2019-08-18 17:38:26.264502 6 3
Tick:  2019-08-18 17:38:27.263805 Hello
```

What I am trying to do is, use the values of Out1 & Out2 in Clock.  Why did I use global, because I don't know any better :)

Comment: Why are you passing the functions at `args=[tick, tock]`? Why are you using globals `Out1` and `Out2`, but then passing them into `clock`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Carcigenicate for asking those questions.  It made me think further and solve my problem.  I was not thinking, I suppose.  The answer is simple once it is fixed!  It is posted here for novices like me... :)

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

Out1 = 0
Out2 = 1
print('Out1 = {}; Out2 = {}'.format(Out1, Out2))

def tick(Msg):
    global Out1
    print('Tick:  {} {} {} {}'.format(datetime.now(), Msg, Out1, Out2))
    Out1 += 1
    return

def tock(Msg):
    global Out2
    print(' Tock: {} {} {} {}'.format(datetime.now(), Msg, Out1, Out2))
    Out2 += 2
    return

def Clock():
    print('\tClock: {} {} {}'.format(datetime.now(), Out1, Out2))
    return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=1,args=["Hello"])
    scheduler.add_job(tock, 'interval', seconds=5,args=["Bye.."])
    scheduler.add_job(Clock, 'interval', seconds=2)

    print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')

    try:
        scheduler.start()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
print('\t You made me quit !')
```